# converting number to vector of number matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to convert an input, lets say `012 into [0 1 2]`, once that is done i want to convert array of number into letters.

`[0 1 2] ---> abc` where `0=a, 1=b, 2=c` and so on.

I want to do this without using any built in Matlab function

This is what I have

```
elseif isnumeric(result) % This else if statement will check if input is a number
alph = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
letters1 = alph(result); % This will convert letters to numbers
disp(letters1); 
disp(' converted number to letters');
```

This code only works when the input is an array and it won't work for an input of 0.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Working with the ascii-representation of the chars, this is very simple:

```
char(result+'a')
```

For 0 the result is `a`, for 1 the result is `a+1` which is `b`...